# Python/Excel - transpose row to column

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to format a print statement to align a specific column.

Here is my dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"platform":['test3','test3','test3','test4','test4','test5','test5','test5','test6','test6'],
                   "ripenes type":['OverRipes', 'Ripes','UnRipes','Ripes','UnRipes','OverRipes', 'Ripes','UnRipes', 'Ripes', 'UnRipes'],
                   "total":[1,5,5,5,4,5,4,1,11,1]})

df
```

Currently my output is:

[image]

The output I am looking for is:

[image]

is there any available method to transpose my data or using python code to create this data frame?

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20170164) for why. Please see [how to format a table in a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/20170164)

Comment: Note your output for **test5 - UnRipes** should be `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [df.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) function.

Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"platform":['test3','test3','test3','test4','test4','test5','test5','test5','test6','test6'],
                   "ripenes type":['OverRipes', 'Ripes','UnRipes','Ripes','UnRipes','OverRipes', 'Ripes','UnRipes', 'Ripes', 'UnRipes'],
                   "total":[1,5,5,5,4,5,4,1,11,1]})

df2 = df.pivot(index="platform", columns="ripenes type", values="total").fillna(0)

# Provide the desired column order
column_order = ['Ripes', 'UnRipes', 'OverRipes']
df2 = df2.reindex(column_order, axis=1)
df2
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Note: You can find some other useful pandas functions on their [official cheatsheet](https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf)